# How can I delete my account from SE?

Tags: discussion

Sorry to bother you here! I asked SE team to delete my profile 3 days ago but I found it is suspended only. I asked them to delete it again and they did but I was not sure about my account and my guess came true! I asked this question here because I cannot ask it in meta. It needs 5 reputations and more. Please bear in mind it is not about deleting a profile or make it anonymous but about main data and whole the account. I am sure you know they are different.

Comment: Please see this site to know how to delete your account: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account.

Comment: And also don't re-create your account and then complain that it hasn't been deleted.

Comment: Epi, I checked it but it is only about deleting a profile and my account and its contents and all data remain here! I do not want to have any data here and want to remove all of them.

Comment: Kit, Sorry but I guess you did not get the matter. I singed up to know if there is any account or has been deleted and knew by this I can find out the matter. Surely it was not to reactive it again.

Comment: You did delete it. Then you came back and made a new account. All of your old questions were anonymized.

Comment: I asked Kit via e mail and she addressed to send my request for team and I did it but the address of mods and team are same may you know about too. I think you need to change some of your policies which seems ridiculous as a look from outside of your group. When you make new account suspended I will not be able to reply your comments so have to make another account and it is very clear it is because of your wrong policies which are not able solve very easy problems. Hope it helps to get it and not spam the question!

Comment: You keep making new accounts. Your questions will not be deleted; see the answer by Andrew below.

Answer (score 10):

Do bear in mind that **just by the act of contributing** you have licensed your content (questions, answers and comments) to Stack Exchange Inc., and you don't have the right to revoke that licence, or to remove your content. If you vandalise your content in an attempt to remove it, it's likely to be restored.

From the [legal page](http://stackexchange.com/legal) on the link at the bottom of each page:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.

It's **possible** that Stack Exchange will consent to waive their rights under this licence, but you will need to ask nicely and convince them of the benefit of doing so.

Comment: This. Exactly this.

Comment: Andrew, Thank you! But bear in mind all above is legal when it is in order to use not abuse. For example if a person prove your abuse (attention! abuse not use) he will be able show your illegal actions too. I agreed with use not abuse.

Comment: @user37313 If you feel your material has been misused, then by all means point examples out in your request to SE. It's difficult to see how the licence I quote can be abused, though. [Meta is **not** the right forum to discuss legal arguments: if you have a legal dispute, you need to raise it with the SE team.]

Comment: Andrew,Thanks again. I got my answer. In case of need I will try ask them again and about your statements which in the other word advices me to write in private about site policies it is because all reactions were in public so I do not hesitate to try the same in public and also It can be a warning for the other users to know the information which are leaving here might be target of abuse by everyone specially mods. A mod is an unknown person who by some votes can be able use of their information even me if I try, so it is better to be more careful about their activities here. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Account deletion only removes your ID from existing content. If you want your content completely purged, you will have to contact team@stackexchange.com and discuss it with them.

You will probably want to have them delete your new account while you're at it. I'm suspending your new one as well per our policy.

Comment: Kit,But it is the same address which I exchanged information with you and you were the person who sent me information by this special address to me! I sent my request to this address before but no appropriate reaction.